# Avoid creation of extra variable while updating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with one key-value pair,

```
dct = {'a': 1}
```

I want to add more key-value pairs to this dictionary, so, I do,

```
{dct.update(**i) for i in [{'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': None}] if any(i.values())}
```

but the IDE starts suggesting to convert this into a variable, and marks the above line with a yellowish background

```
var = {dct.update(**i) for i in [{'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': None}] if any(i.values())}
```

then I add this variable, but it would go unused, and the IDE starts saying unused variable `var`.

How do I update the dictionary, without IDE having any issues?

Comment: `dct.update(**i)` does not return anything, it would make `dct` `None`

Comment: @apostofes Why not using normal for-loop? Comprehension is not meant to update existing dictionaries.

Comment: that is always an option, but was looking for a way to use comprehension for the same

Comment: Related: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](/q/5753597/4518341)

Answer (score 3):

Do it in the normal way **without using the set-comprehension**

```
for i in [{'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': None}]:
    if any(i.values()):
        dct.update(**i)
```

Since you are not using the result set in your code. It's better to keep simple without using any unnecessary comprehensions.

**Edit**

As mark suggestion, if you have any value `0`, you can do like this

```
for i in [{'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': None}]:
    if any([v for v in i.values() if v not None])
        dct.update(**i)
```

Comment: You may want to be careful if it's possible that one of the values could be `0`. In the case of  `{'d': 0}` you probably do want to include this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about this in terms of key/value pairs, you could turn your dicts into key/value pairs and pass them into update as a flattened list:

```
dct = {'a': 1}

l = [{'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': None}]

dct.update((k, v) for d in l for k, v in d.items() if v is not None)

print(dct)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

This is subtly different from your code of using `any(i.values())` in the case where any of these dicts might have more than on value like: `{'e':100, 'd': None}`. Using the above code, this would add `e` and not `d`, but using the `any` approach you would end up adding the `d: None` key value pair.

Also, be careful with the construct `if any(i.values())` if it possible that any of the values could be `0` to make sure it has the behavior you expect.

Answer (score -1):

have found one way to achieve the same

```
dct = {i: j for i, j in zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, None]) if j}
```

edit

or something like this,

```
dct = {'a': 1}
dct.update({i: j for i, j in zip(['b', 'c', 'd'], [2, 3, None]) if j})
```

Comment: This creates a new dictionary, it doesn't update the existing one

Comment: @wjandrea, edited it slightly